# How to get an attribute of a property in c#?

Tags: c#, reflection

Going direct to the point,

How can I get Property's attribute, and, the type or the value of this attribute? 
For example an attribute like this:

```
[ForeignKey(typeof(SomeObject))]
```

I wanna know or get its type "SomeObject". I know I can get Properties() and etc, but attributes I have no Ideia.

That is a doubt I have and it is freaking me off. Thanks in advance for helpin!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once you've got the [`PropertyInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.propertyinfo.aspx) for the property you're interested in, you just call [`GetCustomAttributes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwc6ew1d.aspx) on it:

```
ForeignKey[] keys = (ForeignKey[]) 
    property.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(ForeignKeyAttribute), false);
```

There's also the [`CustomAttributes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.memberinfo.customattributes.aspx) property, but that's only available in .NET 4.5 and Windows Store apps.

Comment: Also there is a GetCustomAttributesData():- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.memberinfo.getcustomattributesdata.aspx

Comment: @RahulTripathi: Yes, but only as of .NET 4 and it looks rather more cumbersome to use than the code I've given.

Comment: Hi, @JonSkeet! I Wrote something like this: foreach (var property in properties)
   {
    Console.WriteLine(property.Name);

    foreach (ForeignKeyAttribute foreignKey in
             property.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(ForeignKeyAttribute), false))
    {
     Console.WriteLine(foreignKey);
    }  in prompt is printed this: Namespace.Example.Model.ForeignKeyAttribute. It's not satisfactory. Sorry the format of this.

Comment: @RodCosta: Well no, you'd need to fetch the appropriate property from the attribute. Currently you're just calling `ToString()` on the attribute. I'm assuming it has some sort of `ParentType` property or something like that. But the code I've given you is at least getting you the instance of the attribute - what you do with that is up to you.